# Downsides of using single-session tokens vs Oauth for single page web app

Tags: authentication, session, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm building a single-page web app and want to interact with the back-end only via a REST API.  I've read [this page](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/designing-a-restful-web-api) and others with advice on API best practices.

I want the following authentication features:

- Multiple simultaneous (but not linked) sessions permitted for each user (i.e. can log in and out from several devices at once)
- When user logs out from one device, that session is no longer active and can't be reused, but the user's other sessions on other devices are not affected.
- Can open multiple browser tabs to the page and the session is shared between them (no need to sign in on each tab)
- Support Google and facebook authentication buttons (allow users to sign up and authenticate with these services)

Would it make sense to simply issue a per-session token to each authenticated session, something like PHP's session IDs, track these tokens in the app's database, and require that these tokens be included with every API call?  I suppose it could be stored in a cookie so it would be accessible from all browser tabs.
For each API call, this token would be authenticated server-side with the list of valid, active sessions.
When the user logs out, the cookie is deleted and server deletes the active session ID (or it is considered invalid after a period of non-use).

Is there a security hole here?  Yes I realize a malicious user could duplicate the session key and use it to access the API while the user is logged in, but isn't that true also of JWT or an OAuth PKCE token?

How would JWT or OAuth provide an advantage in this use-case? (or would they?)

Comment: Why not using session cookies directly (without your custom tokens)? Take a look at the [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04).

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is as follows, which is close to what you are  asking for I think:

- Log in on tab 1 and interact with the API
- Open the app on tab 2 and you are automatically signed in
- Tab 1 and tab 2 have independent access tokens
- Logout on tab 1 and tab 2 still has a valid access token

You can run my [Online Demo SPA](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) on multiple tabs to see what this looks like.

My preference is for each tab to have its own independent OAuth session, which fits best with the technology.

OAuth does not give you a session key, but you can create one separately - and share it across tabs if required via HTML5 local storage.

Eg. My app uses a session id that correlates to API logs - I do not use the session id for anything secure.